# Use the value of a variable to find an item in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, ionic-framework

I am still having trouble using the var to identify the object in the array. Here is what I have right now:

in controller:

```
$scope.allbooks=[
{book1={title:"Eat Pray Love", price:"$3.99"},
{book2={title:"DaVinci Code", price:"$7.99"}}
]

$scope.pick=function(name){
     $rootScope.choice = name;
}
```

in html template

```
<ion-item ng-click="pick(book1)">

{{allbooks.choice[0].title}} <----This does not work
```

Used an alert to make sure choice=book1 which it does...I don't know what I am doing wrong

PLEASE HELP :(

Comment: Your `allbooks` assignment statement does not look like proper Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
{book1={title:"Eat Pray Love", price:"$3.99"},
{book2={title:"DaVinci Code", price:"$7.99"}}
]
```

is not valid javascript. If you are trying to define an object literal you'll need to adjust your syntax a bit:

```
$scope.allbooks = [
    {title:"Eat Pray Love", price:"$3.99"},
    {title:"DaVinci Code", price:"$7.99"}
]
```

Now you can access each book:

```
$scope.allbooks[0]; // returns first book
$scope.allbooks[1]; // returns second book
```

Comment: I totally get what your saying about the syntax, I think I just typed it in too fast...but how do I  fix this issue    {{allbooks.choice[0].title}}

Comment: {{ allbooks[0].title }} ?

Comment: I will try to explain my issue again...so i want to access this part of an array: {{things.book1.price}} but instead the user chooses which books price to view...so they can pick from any book from book1 to book99...so I need to replace {{things.book1.price}} with {{things.choice.price}} where choice will be assigned based on user choice

Answer (score 1):

in controller:

```
$scope.allbooks=[
  {book1:{title:"Eat Pray Love", price:"$3.99"}},
  {book2:{title:"DaVinci Code", price:"$7.99"}}
];

$scope.choice = {}; //a variable to store your choice

$scope.pick=function(name){
     $scope.choice = $scope.allbooks[name];  
}
```

in html template

```
<ion-item ng-click="pick('book1')"> <!-- pass book1 as string -->

{{choice.title}}
```

---

---

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("main", function($scope) {

    $scope.allbooks = {
      book1: {
        title: "Eat Pray Love",
        price: "$3.99"
      },
      book2: {
        title: "DaVinci Code",
        price: "$7.99"
      }
    };

    $scope.choice = {}; //a variable to store your choice

    $scope.pick = function(name) {
      $scope.choice = $scope.allbooks[name];
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">

  <button ng-click="pick('book1')">Test</button>
  <!-- pass book1 as string -->

  {{choice.title}}

</div>
```

Comment: missed a '}' for book1

Comment: I tried but it didn't work...if i just use {{allbooks.book1.title}} it works but as soon as i try to dynamically replace it with the variable it falls apart :(

Comment: have you defined `$scope.choice ` variable in your scope?

Comment: I am using $rootScope.choice instead of $scope.choice so it should be available to all the scopes...(but I might not be correct)

Comment: button does not work anymore...i had to change <ion-item ng-click="pick('book1')"> to <ion-item ng-click=pick('book1')> but it is still not working....whats crazy is that I was able to get {{choice}} to work and it showed book1 in the html file...this makes no sense

Comment: is your `{{choice.title}}` outputs `book1` details?

Comment: no, just {{choice}} outputs book1 but as soon as i pair it with the array it doesnt work...so right now it is just outputting the variable

Comment: is your `$scope.allbooks` must be an array?

Comment: I change `$scope.allbooks` array to object. It might work now

Comment: yes...have you tried it on your computer and is it working?

Comment: I attached a snipped try that

Comment: it seems to be working for the snippet...can you upload all the code you used

Comment: it works but i because you used $scope and not $rootScope the variable is not accessible from the other controllers...do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to access parent controller you can use `$scope.$parent`

Comment: Could you eloborate...sorry I am really new to coding and angularjs